# Xcode error when ctrl-dragging image to new class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I already asked this in the Apple Dev Forum but received no replies, so I'll try here.

I'm unsure if this is a bug or whether I've missed something since I'm still very new to programming.

I have multiple view controllers and have made multiple classes. I have set the custom class "bit" of each view controller to the revelent class. When I ctrl-drag anything from the view to the relevent class header, I get the usual pop-up. I fill in the info, press connect, and BAM. It does the same kind of error whether I choose "Outlet" or "Action" It worked in the previous Xcode but I'm not sure if I've forgotten something.

The view controller and class that I added with Xcode 4 is still working beatifully.

I've tried adding the image manually but all that gave me was a SIGBART error just trying to get to the view. Again, I may have missed something, but I don't think there's much to miss is there?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Xcode error]

Just to eliminate a few things... I've deleted derived data, restarted Xcode and done a "clean". That's all I can remember that I've done.

Comment: And what about the error message?  Does it ring any bells?

Comment: What do you mean? I've never had it before.

Comment: The error message in the pop-up window: "Could not find any information for the class named FourInchPanicViewController".  Is that class correctly defined?

Comment: I think so... Your talking about this bit: `@interface FourInchPanicViewController : UIViewController` right? I just made a an "Objective-C Class" and "connected" it up with the right view. That's all I did, have I missed something important? Sorry If I misunderstood your comment since I'm still very new to programming

Comment: Well this is the root cause of the error by the look of it.  Check the header and implementation file are added to the project and there are no syntax errors in the file (look at the log pane with the triangle and !).

Comment: Well, while taking a look, just by pure luck, I stumble across the "Target Membership". On the class that was working properly, the app name was ticked, but on the ones that weren't working, It was unticked. So I ticked it. I noticed that some text in the implementation file now change from black to different colours and It now works properly! Thanks for your help trojanfoe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

When selecting the implementation file. When I looked in the File Inspector, I found that under "Target Membership", the app name wasn't ticked. I ticked it and it now works well.

Since I didn't need to do that in Xcode 4, I suspect in Xcode 5, it doesn't do that automatically. Maybe that's a bug? I don't know if it was deliberate by Apple, but I think I'll file a bug report anyway since It's a bit of a nuisance.